# Getting Radio button work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I need a jQuery function that when I select the fifth radio button and then click next button to send me to another html page.

```js
$jquery('#5').click(function() {
  //when 5 is selected and then i click next go to another html page
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1s">first<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2s">2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3s">3<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="4">4<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="5">5 (if this is selected go to another html page)<br>
  <input type="button" id="button" onclick="" value="Next">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this into your function

```
window.location.replace("INSERT HTML PAGE URL");
```

or you can do

```
window.location.href("INSERT HTML PAGE URL");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
   if($(':radio[value="5"]:checked').length){ //jquery to understaind if element exist
      window.location.href="myurl";
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  var rvalue=$('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
  if(rvalue==5) {
    $("#myform").attr('action','http://jsfiddle.net/' );
    $("#myform").submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" action="">
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1s">first<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2s">2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3s">3<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="4">4<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="5">5 <br>
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Next">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
   if($(':radio[value="5"]:checked').length){
      $(this).closest('form').submit();
   }
});
```

or:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
   if($(':radio[value="5"]').prop('checked')){ // .prop() resutls in true/false
      $(this).closest('form').submit();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

see if selected radio button has value 5 on next click. if yes then redirect,else return. write below code in next button click handler.

```
if ($('input[name="answer"]:radio:checked').val()=="5"){
   //redirect 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check on the radio button while clicking

so your code can be something like

```
$("#button").click(function(){
   if($(this).parent('form').children('input:radio:checked').val() == '5'){
      window.location.href="http://google.com"; // replace it with your url
      return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you to get the data from the form and use it for the subsequent actions :

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
    if ($( this ).serialize().split("=")[1] == 5){
        location.href= "http://www.facebook.com";
    }
});
```

this will get the value of your selected radio button on form submit and redirect on selecting 5 and clicking next.

fiddle demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/GrL9a/